# Booleans statement not working?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

The code below I take in two arrays and compare them. When thay are both the same I get the correct messsage displaying but when it is false both messages display. The very last if statement to display *System.out.println("identical");* always seems to display even when booleans is false. Why is this????

```
public static void compareArrays(int[] a, int[] n){

  boolean b = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i] == a[i]) {
        b = true;
    } else {
        b = false;
        System.out.println("different");
        break;
    }
  } 

  if (b = true){
    System.out.println("identical");
  } 
}
```

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvote, since I don't think it is deserved. It is obvious what is asked, and I'm not sure what I would search for to find an answer to this problem as an unexperienced programmer.

Comment: -1. It's very confusing, that you changed the question significantly. Rather let the error in the question, and mark an answer as accepted. Fix the error in your IDE, though ;)

Comment: @user2052514, revert your code edit to previous version, else all of below answers will become invalid :)

Comment: I rolled back the final change because its edited made the question non-sensical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`=`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) is an assignment operator. [`==`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) is the equality operator.

```
if (b = true){
```

should be

```
if (b ==true){
```

or as `b` is boolean simply:

```
  if(b) {
```

Answer (score 12):

Change this:

```
if (b = true){
    System.out.println("identical");
}
```

to:

```
if (b == true){
    System.out.println("identical");
}
```

or better

```
if (b){
    System.out.println("identical");
}
```

You are assigning a value instead of comparing.

Comment: +1 For the "or better" section.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't compare `b` to true but *set* it before the if-statement is executed.

Change the if-statement to either `if(b == true)` or simply `if(b)`.